# Avoiding Overflow using l+(r-l)/2

Tags: c++, mergesort, integer-overflow

When I was learning Merge Sort implementation, I came across the code below:

```
// Same as (l+r)/2, but avoids overflow for 
// large l and h 
int m = l+(r-l)/2;
```

1. How is (l+r)/2 same as l+(r-l)/2? The latter evaluates into r/2.
2. How does (l+r)/2 cause overflow and how does l+(r-l)/2 fix the problem?
3. What's h? (I think it's a typo which is meant to be r)

Comment: `(l+r-l)/2` simplifies (mathematically) to `r/2`. `l + (r-l)/2` indeed simplifies to `(l+r)/2`, for example, by expanding it into `l + r/2 - l/2` -> `l/2 + r/2` -> `(l+r)/2`.

Comment: note that, for `int l,r`, `4+3 => 4+(3-4)/2 = 4`, but `3+4 = 3 + (4-3)/2 = 3` (while `(4+3)/2 = 3`)

Comment: My bad. I thought that the numerator was l+(r-1) the whole time.

Comment: Such a hack may avoid overflow if `r` and `l` are both large.  However, it also can also introduce overflow - that would not occur in calculating `(l + r)/2` - if `r` is a large value and `l` is a small value of opposite sign.    So the hack doesn't avoid overflow - it simply changes the conditions in which overflow will occur.    (Assuming that the compiler doesn't "optimise out" the different way of doing the calculations).   In this case, I'd be more concerned about the fact that `l` (letter) and `1` (digit) are visually similar, so it is really hard to visually detect any typo).

Comment: @Peter Thanks for the side notes. Since this is a code about merge sort, l and r represents an index of array, hence it won't be negative. This hack is actually a smart one.

Comment: @Peter Since this is merge sort, there is an implicit `0 <= l < r`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Please check again - it expands to `l + r/2 - l/2` which is `l/2 + r/2`. Note that we can't just use `l/2 + r/2` as there will be integer truncation, so `3/2 + 5/2` = `1 + 2` = `3`, but the desired value is `4`.
2. Assume that both `l` and `r` are positive values of type `int`.

If we have:

```
int l = INT_MAX - 2;
int r = INT_MAX;
```

Then the `l + r` part is `INT_MAX - 2 + INT_MAX`, which is an integer overflow. `INT_MAX - 2 + (INT_MAX - (INT_MAX - 2))/2` has no integer overflows as each sub-expression remains between `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX`.

3. Yes, that's a typo!